# How can I plot hours on the y-axis?

Tags: r, twitter, time-series

I'm trying to analyze some Twitter data. You can finde the my R code here:

I don't understand how I can extract and plot the the value "hours" from my dataset on my y-axis. Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
# data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")
data <- read.csv(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 text = '"time","impressions","engagements"
                 "1",2015-10-24 15:39:00,400,"8.0"
                 "2",2015-10-24 15:28:00,575,"17.0"
                 "3",2015-10-23 16:52:00,1646,"29.0"
                 "4",2015-10-23 16:45:00,1489,"46.0"')
# remove duplicate rows
# data <- data[-c(177, 323, 615, 497, 809), ]
data$impressions <-as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))
data$engagement <-as.numeric(as.character(data[,3]))

# Convert times to POSIXct
data$time <- as.POSIXct(data$time)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=impressions)) +
theme_bw() +
geom_point(shape = 21, color = "red", size = data$engagement*0.1, position = position_jitter(width = 0.5)) +  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks=0,breaks=seq(0,2000,200),limits=c(0,2000))
```

data looks like that

```
"time","impressions","engagements"
"1",2015-10-24 15:39:00,400,"8.0"
"2",2015-10-24 15:28:00,575,"17.0"
"3",2015-10-23 16:52:00,1646,"29.0"
"4",2015-10-23 16:45:00,1489,"46.0"
```

Comment: what about appending `scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")` to `ggplot`? I'm not sure exactly what you want the labels to be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to extract hours (since your Time column is properly formatted), is to use the hour() function from the lubridate package in R.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")

# remove duplicate rows
data <- data[-c(177, 323, 615, 497, 809), ]

data$impressions <-as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))
data$engagement <-as.numeric(as.character(data[,3]))
# extract hour from time column
data$Hour <- lubridate::hour(data$time)
```